manim - Can't animate a 3D Coin Flip
I am trying to animate a coin flip using Manim.
For that I create a VGroup with a central Cylinder and two Dots for the two sides.
Still, when I rotate the object the bottom part doesn't come to the front, it' like the front side always stays there. Can someone help me?
class Coin(VGroup):

    def __init__(self, radius=1, height=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        if height is None:
            height = radius / 4

        self.top = Dot(radius=radius, color=GOLD_D, fill_opacity=1)
        self.top.move_to(OUT*height/2)
        
        self.bottom = self.top.copy()
        self.bottom.set_color(RED)
        self.bottom.move_to(IN*height/2)
        
        self.edge = Cylinder(radius=radius, height=height)
        self.edge.set_fill(GREY, opacity=1)
        # rotate the cylinder so that the upper face is towards the camera
        self.edge.rotate(90 * DEGREES, OUT)
        
        self.add(self.edge, self.bottom,  self.top)
    

class CoinFlip(Scene):
    
    def construct(self):
        c = Coin()
    
        self.play(Rotate(c, PI*.8, axis=RIGHT, about_point=ORIGIN))


maybe first you should rotate only one side (without showing second side) , and later rotate only second side (without showing first side). OR maybe you should use only one dot for all

you could create minimal working code so we could simply copy and test it. I would allow to see this problem in animation.

I create two coins with different order of elements top and bottom

first with self.add(self.edge, self.bottom, self.top)
second with self.add(self.edge, self.top, self.bottom)

And later I animate rotation of one of them and I only rotate (without animation) other of them (and I remove it from scene)
I add linear function to run many animations in the same way.
I also slow down it to see if it works correctly

from manim import *

class Coin(VGroup):

    def __init__(self, radius=1, height=None, flip=False, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        if height is None:
            height = radius / 4

        self.top = Dot(radius=radius, color=GOLD_D, fill_opacity=1)
        self.top.move_to(OUT*height/2)
        
        self.bottom = self.top.copy()
        self.bottom.set_color(RED)
        self.bottom.move_to(IN*height/2)
        
        self.edge = Cylinder(radius=radius, height=height)
        self.edge.set_fill(GREY, opacity=1)
        
        # rotate the cylinder so that the upper face is towards the camera
        self.edge.rotate(90 * DEGREES, OUT)
        
        if not flip:
            self.add(self.edge, self.bottom, self.top)
        else:
            self.add(self.edge, self.top, self.bottom)
    

class CoinFlip(Scene):
    
    def construct(self):
        #print('90 DEGREES:', 90 * DEGREES)
        #print('PI * .8   :', PI * .8)

        c1 = Coin()
        c2 = Coin(flip=True)        

        self.add(c1)
        self.remove(c2)
        self.play(Rotate(c1, 90*DEGREES, axis=RIGHT, about_point=ORIGIN),  run_time=2, rate_func=linear)
        c2.rotate(90*DEGREES, axis=RIGHT, about_point=ORIGIN)

        self.remove(c1)
        self.add(c2)
        c1.rotate(180*DEGREES, axis=RIGHT, about_point=ORIGIN)
        self.play(Rotate(c2, 180*DEGREES, axis=RIGHT, about_point=ORIGIN), run_time=4, rate_func=linear)
        
        self.add(c1)
        self.remove(c2)
        self.play(Rotate(c1, 90*DEGREES, axis=RIGHT, about_point=ORIGIN),  run_time=2, rate_func=linear)
        c2.rotate(90*DEGREES, axis=RIGHT, about_point=ORIGIN)


After some time I released that it can be done with one coin and with remove() and add() to change order of elements self.top, self.bottom in this single coin.
I found that there is function add_to_back() so I named my function add_to_front().
But you may also use add_to_back() to move all other elements.
I added it to code.
from manim import *

class Coin(VGroup):

    def __init__(self, radius=1, height=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        if height is None:
            height = radius / 4

        self.top = Dot(radius=radius, color=GOLD_D, fill_opacity=1)
        self.top.move_to(OUT*height/2)
        
        self.bottom = self.top.copy()
        self.bottom.set_color(RED)
        self.bottom.move_to(IN*height/2)
        
        self.edge = Cylinder(radius=radius, height=height)
        self.edge.set_fill(GREY, opacity=1)
        
        # rotate the cylinder so that the upper face is towards the camera
        self.edge.rotate(90 * DEGREES, OUT)
        
        self.add(self.edge, self.bottom, self.top)
    
    def add_to_front(self, *items):
        self.remove(*items)
        self.add(*items)
    

class CoinFlip(Scene):
    
    def construct(self):
        print('90 DEGREES:', 90 * DEGREES)
        print('PI * .8   :', PI * .8)

        coin = Coin()

        time = 2

        time_text = Text(f"time: {time} s").next_to(coin, UP)
        self.add(time_text)

        #c1.add_to_front(coin.top)               # own function
        #c1.add_to_back(coin.edge, coin.bottom)  # built-in function
        self.play(Rotate(coin, 90*DEGREES, axis=RIGHT, about_point=ORIGIN),  run_time=time/4, rate_func=linear)

        #c1.add_to_front(coin.bottom)            # own function
        c1.add_to_back(coin.edge, coin.top)      # built-in function
        self.play(Rotate(coin, 180*DEGREES, axis=RIGHT, about_point=ORIGIN), run_time=time/2, rate_func=linear)
        
        #c1.add_to_front(coin.top)               # own function
        c1.add_to_back(coin.edge, coin.bottom)   # built-in function
        self.play(Rotate(coin, 90*DEGREES, axis=RIGHT, about_point=ORIGIN),  run_time=time/4, rate_func=linear)


I added version which uses add() remove() to change order of self.top, self.bottom - so it needs only one object Coin()
